# Add rows of values before last row and preserve last row format

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am pretty new to Google Sheets API so bear with me.
I have a spreadsheet that acts as a template, with the last two rows formatted in some specific way (colors and font).

It looks like something like this:

```
| header 1     | header 2     | header 3     |
| placeholder1 | placeholder2 | placeholder3 |
| color footer1|color footer2 | color footer2|
```

What I want to do is inserting as many "placeholder" rows as I need, and let the last row 'slide' down.

So far I tried [`values.update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) which does insert new rows, but doesn't move down the colors of the last line. So that I end up with the data in the spreadsheet as I want, but with the wrong color formatting (basically the third row will always have a coloured background, whereas the last one doesn't).

The psuedocode I am thinking to do:

1. Count how many placeholders rows I need to add in,
2. Get spreadsheet
3. Cut+paste the last two lines to the new position
4. Get values of the spreadsheet
5. Update values (replace placeholders, insert new rows, update totals)

I am not sure it is the best way to go about (seems a bit complex). Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Share the different requests you've tried.

Comment: I actually ended up using `batchUpdate` and send a `updateCells` request

Comment: good advice, thanks. I'll put in a brief answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I decided to use [spreadsheet.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to retrieve the template.

I set the flag `includeGridData` to true, which sends back all the information for each cell.

It's a big object, but it has all I needed.

Then I clone the template row, generated as many copies as I needed.

Finally I put those new rows back in the rows object returned by `get` (without the template row) and then use [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to update the spreadsheeet.

Something like this:

```
async updateSpreadsheetCells(clone, data, spreadSheetDataRows) {
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: clone.id,
    resource: {
      requests: [
        {
          updateCells: {
            fields: '*',
            range: {
              sheetId: 0,
              startRowIndex: 0,
              endRowIndex: endRow // value dynamically calculated
              startColumnIndex: 0,
              endColumnIndex: this.endColumnIndex
            },
            rows: spreadSheetDataRows //this will replace all the rows
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  await this.googleSheetService.batchUpdateSpreadSheet(request);
}
```

It's a quick overview, the code is a bit complex and no point to post it here. Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: consider supplying the `fields` parameter in your `spreadsheet.get` request - you can limit the retrieved data to only that which you need: Interactive fields builder is on the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get) page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying the formatting to the cells, you could apply conditional formatting, and have it always match the data of the final cells.

For example, per [this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zHRKHGyCi7M) you can apply the following conditional formatting to always apply to the final row by having it apply to A2:Z999

> =Arrayformula(Row($A2:$A) = Max((Row($A2:$A))*(($A2:$A<>""))))

Or alternatively have some data that is always only going to be in the final row, and format based off of it matching that data.

However, note that if you are creating entirely new rows the conditional formatting could surpass row Z in which case your conditional formatting no longer applies (without manually updating which rows it applies to, extending it's reach). This may limit the usability of this method depending on what you need it for.